# Characters of simple $\mathfrak{sl}_n$-modules in positive characteristic with subregular nilpotent central character

Tags: rt.representation-theory, characters, modular-representation-theory, positive-characteristic, modular-lie-algebras

Consider representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ in positive characteristic with a subregular nilpotent central character $\chi$ (i.e. $\chi$ is a nilpotent matrix whose Jordan normal form has two blocks of size $n-1$ and $1$). For every regular weight $\lambda$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, we have the simple module $L_{\chi}(\lambda)$. My question is, how to compute the character of $L_{\chi}(\lambda)$?

Comment: Have you tried looking at Jantzen's older papers? IIRC he has an paper where he computes irreps corresponding to subregular characters explicitly (in simply laced types?) My understanding is that this was one of the motivations for Lusztig's conjectures on counts of irreps and Springer fibres.